# SOLVED :Why am I having "Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML"?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get data from my API to the main page but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost/PaimentElec/server/apiDetails.php?xml=<movie><id>2</id></movie> ): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaimentElec\client\rep.php on line 19
**Fatal error**: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaimentElec\client\rep.php:20 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PaimentElec\client\rep.php(20): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaimentElec\client\rep.php on line 20
```

At first I thought maybe I have errors in my API XML, so I used https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp to double check and it said that my code is fine. When I open the link for the API (e.g. `http://localhost/PaimentElec/server/apiDetails.php?xml=<movie><id>2</id></movie>`) it shows the data perfectly.

This is the API:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<movies>
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=homecinema","root","");
    $xml=$_GET["xml"];
    $retour= new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $id=$retour->id;
    $retour=$db->query("select * from movie where id='$id' ");
    $movies=$retour->fetchAll(); 
    foreach($movies as $movie){
    ?>
      <movie>
      <title> <?php echo $movie ["title"];?></title>
      </movie>
<?php   
}?>
</movies>
```

and this is where I called the API (page name rep.php):

```
$id=$_POST["id"];    //this is the line 19
$xmlrq="<movie><id>$id</id></movie>";
$xml=file_get_contents("http://localhost/PaimentElec/server/apiDetails.php?xml=$xmlrq");
$retour= new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

PS: the id was sent by another page:

```
<form method="POST" action="rep.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $movie->id; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: The error says `xml=2`. It also says `file_get_contents` is on line 19. This doesn't match what you're showing now. Did you have an earlier version of the file where you were directly adding the id to the url?

Comment: I don't know why it's shown this way in the question even when i tried to edit it it always the same , i wrote "xml=<movie><id>2</id></movie>"

Comment: Transferring XML through the query parameters seems a weird choice. It'd be more sensible to make a `POST` request with an XML body.

Comment: Can you `urlencode` the `$xmlrq`?

Comment: @user3783243 I will try this and see what it gives me thank you

Comment: Did that give something back?

Comment: @user3783243 okai so I finally got to know the error : I had an API that send the id to that "other page" (the form) however in that API the id was sent with an extra space that's why the result of this :<?php echo $movie->id ?> has an extra space, as a result the id wasn't recognised.

Answer (score -1):

The string which you receive is not valid xml. here you can check for correct standard of XML https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp, but I suggest you to forget for xml (if it's possible) because XML is old and not best solution, for web you can use JSON.

Comment: I would love to use jsons but my teacher wants us to use "his way" for the project, I will try the link you sent me hope i get it to work . Thank you.

Comment: Not entirely sure about the context but think the edits a bit better. `old` isn't a good reason to not use something.

Comment: Suggesting that someone uses a completely different technology for their project is not usually a helpful answer. In addition, your reference to w3schools is completely off the mark: w3schools is not generally authoritative, the page in question is about XSD not XML, and the page doesn't help the user to establish why their XML is invalid.